# rsyslogd and FQDN - cannot get FQDN from clients

Tags: hostname, syslog, rsyslog, fqdn

I setup a syslogserver with rsyslogd and 3 clients. 
Logs from 3 test clients are sent to the server, so far so good. 
My Problem is: 
I can't get the FQDN hostnames to work. 
According to rsyslog.com i have to add "$PreserveFQDN on" in /etc/rsyslog.conf. 
I changed this on the server and the 3 clients, restarted rsyslogd and still the short hostname, but if i restart the rsyslogd service on one client it create a log file on the server with its FQDN...

hostname --long gives a good client.example.org result 
hostname --short gives client which is fine too.

Any Ideas?? 
Thanks in advanced!

Comment: OK found a workaround: Add the Clients to Servers /etc/hosts and changed at server /etc/rsyslog.conf Templatevariable from %HOSTNAME% to %formhost%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case you keep looking for it, here's the answer.

At rsyslog server, if for example you have defined this template for remote logs, you should use `%FROMHOST%` variable instead of `%HOSTNAME%` :

```
$template RemoteLogs, "/media/largeHDD/logs/%FROMHOST%/%PROGRAMNAME%.log" *
*.*  ?RemoteLogs
& ~
```